# cannot resolve symbol error on a content parameter

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm getting this error on android

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(InscActivity.this, Home_screen.class);
```

I've searched multiple posts about this problem and couldn't find a solution can anyone help?

Error:

> cannot resolve symbol Home_screen.class

Comment: do you have it on your manifest?

Comment: yes, I do have it on my manifest, and on Home_screen there's an error, it says "unresolved class Home_screen".

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly the case if your current class, doesn't know, where to look for your `Home_screen` class. You have to tell your class the location of this class like

```
import com.example.yourproject.Home_screen
```

Do this above the declaration of your class, where your error throwing code is in.

Comment: should I replace example with something specific ? if so , what is it ? and how do I know my project name ? because I wrote com.example.donation.Home_screen (donation is the project name as far as I know) and I have cannot resolve symbol error on "example".

Comment: I also tried "com.myname.donation.Home_screen" and I got "cannot resolve  symbol Home_screen" error

Comment: try com.donation.Home_screen, or instead com the suffix of your local domain (like, en. / fr. / de. / etc). The full package name of your project is also mentioned in your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the mainfest tag

Answer (score 0):

As per java naming convention

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).
>   [Reference to documentation here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411).

If you change name of class to **HomeScreen** or **Homescreen** it will work fine.